# Webdriver script working fine in FF17,But not working in IE7

Tags: eclipse, firefox, internet-explorer-7, stack-trace, selenium-webdriver

Below Webdriver script woking fine for FF17,But getting error in IE-7.I have changed protected mode of IE.Still no output.

public class driver{

```
DefaultSelenium selenium;
private WebDriver driver;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {


    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);        
}
@Test
public void testTimeWebdriver(){

    try {

        WebElement userName, passWord, submit;
        driver.manage().getCookies();

        driver.get("http://www.google.co.in/");
        //driver.manage().;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq").sendKeys("hello"));



        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfba")).click();


        WaitForPageToLoad wait = new WaitForPageToLoad();
        wait.setTimeToWait(30000);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
        fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
}
```

Error Getting for IE :Error :Unable to find element with name == userid (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information); duration or timeout: 30.07 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.8.0', revision: '14056', time: '2011-10-06 12:41:26'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_38'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver don't support `IE7`. You can use `IE8 or higher version` for it.

Comment: What's the source of this info? The wiki page states it has been tested from ie6 onwards..  http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Comment: I have tried this code in IE8 also.Getting same error.Then i have degraded to IE7.Is it confirmed that Webdriver not working for IE7 ?